# How to mock window.Intercom() in jasmine test for angularjs?

Tags: jasmine

my app.js .run has 'window.Intercom("test");' but when i run jasmine test its throwing error 'TypeError: window.Intercom is not a function' how can i resolve this.

app.js

```
.run(..., function(...){

  window.Intercom("test");

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside beforeEach() try mocking the function with this:

```
window.Intercom =  jasmine.createSpy('')
```

or

```
window['Intercom'] =  jasmine.createSpy('')
```